# Fill and Launch a FLOW from APEX after submitting a form from LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, visual-workflow, developer

So instead of inserting directly using apex a new record of which the fields are being filled in a form by the user ! I want to do that using a FLOW, so I want to fill the FLOW by the form values and launch it!
So far I am passing the values from the client side to Apex, and then I want to pass those values to the FLOW !

my apex function looks like this:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static void createContactFormRecord(Contact_form__c contactFormRecord) {
        if (contactFormRecord != null) {
            // create security boundary, only use these fields.
            Contact_form__c newContactForm = new Contact_form__c();
            // Subject__c does not exist!
            newContactForm.Email__c = contactFormRecord.Email__c;
            newContactForm.First_name__c = contactFormRecord.First_name__c;
            newContactForm.Last_name__c = contactFormRecord.Last_name__c;
            newContactForm.Order__c = contactFormRecord.Order__c;
            newContactForm.Comment__c = contactFormRecord.Comment__c;
            newContactForm.Phone__c = contactFormRecord.Phone__c;
            newContactForm.Reason_1__c = contactFormRecord.Reason_1__c;
            newContactForm.Reason_2__c = contactFormRecord.Reason_2__c;
            //newContactForm.Reason_3__c = contactFormRecord.Reason_3__c;
            newContactForm.Country__c = contactFormRecord.Country__c;
            newContactForm.Language__c = contactFormRecord.Language__c;
                    
            Map<String, Object> myMap = new Map<String, Object>();
            // this is where I am supposed to fill the map object that i will pass to the the flow

            Flow.Interview.Create_ContactForm myFlow = new Flow.Interview.Create_ContactForm(new Map<String, Object>());
            myFlow.start();
        }
    return null;
    }
```

And the flow in salesforce looks to something like this:

[image]

I did some googling but couldn't find any accurate help
any thoughts developers
any help would be appreciated
thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost done the needed work. You just need to fill in the map you instantiated and pass it as a constructor parameter.

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = new Map<String, Object>();
// this is where I am supposed to fill the map object that i will pass to the the flow
myMap.put( 'Comment', contactFormRecord.Comment__c ); //Key is the name of your variable from the flow 
myMap.put( 'Country', contactFormRecord.Country__c);
...
Flow.Interview.Create_ContactForm myFlow = new Flow.Interview.Create_ContactForm( myMap );
myFlow.start();
```

Please refer to [this help page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/flow_interview_class.htm) for more information about Interview class, where you can find an example:

```
Interview Created Statically for a Local Flow
{
  Map<String, Object> inputs = new Map<String, Object>();
  inputs.put('AccountID', myAccount);
  inputs.put('OpportunityID', myOppty);
  
  Flow.Interview.Calculate_discounts myFlow = 
    new Flow.Interview.Calculate_discounts(inputs);
  myFlow.start();
}
```